# How to Make Loading in Image Slideshow Swift

Tags: swift, slideshow, kingfisher

so, i'm using swift library [ImageSlideshow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) and use KingfisherSource to set image. I get the url image from Alamofire request

How to make loading/activity indicator before image showed?

Here's my code:

```
var arrayImage = [InputSource]()

for data in items{                  
      let Menu = ModelBanner()                  
      Menu.id = (data["id"].intValue)
      Menu.banner = (data["banner"].stringValue)
      self.listBanner.append(Menu)
      self.arrayImage.append(KingfisherSource(urlString: data["banner"].stringValue)!)                       
    }
      self.slideImage.contentScaleMode = .scaleAspectFill
      self.slideImage.setImageInputs(self.arrayImage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add activity indicator from the storyboard over your UIImageView.
2. Connect an outlet from the activity indicator to your ViewController file
3. In viewDidLoad(), `activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true`
4. Within your Alamofire request, use `activityIndicator.startAnimating()`
5. Once you get the call back from Alamofire, in the completion handler, use `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`

Above code assumes `activityIndicator` is the outlet connection name of the `UIActivityIndicatorView`

Answer (score 0):

Better way to show activity indicator is to use the default implementation.

```
slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
```

You can customize style and color of the indicator:

```
slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator(style: .white, color: nil)
```

There's also an option to use your own activity indicator. You just need to implement `ActivityIndicatorView` and `ActivityIndicatorFactory` protocols.

For more details see the **Activity Indicator** section [here](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow).